# How to refactor two Django querysets that match

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have two models that no have relationship, I match
with one of its fields in this case `area_ref` with`resource_ref`

For example:

Match is found: 
`area_ref = 'L020202'` with `resource_ref = 'L020202'`

Models...

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    area_ref = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Resource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    resource_ref = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm currently doing it with lists

```
area = Area.objects.values('area_ref')
area_list_ref = []

for _a in area:
    area_list_ref.append(_a.get('area_ref'))

resource = Resource.objects.filter(resource_ref__in=area_list_ref)
```

It works, but when it finds several matches it takes a long time

Any better ideas?

Comment: It looks like you might want to create a `ForeignKey` from `Resource` to `Area` or something similar, not to perform `JOIN`s by using values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can boost performance by making a database *index* for the `resource_ref` column:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    resource_ref = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this will boost a lookup.

We can furthermore combine the two querysets, and query with:

```
resource = Resource.objects.filter(
    resource_ref__in=Area.objects.values('area_ref')
)
```

This will then perform a subquery to obtain the items that should be fetched.

But it looks like you "mimic" a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) here. It looks like both `Area` and `Resource` have some sort of relation to a "third model". It might be better to introduce relations, since the database can check referential integrity, and it makes querying more convenient.